Mismatch between the processor architecture error with x86 .dll only in Visual Studio 2022
Visual Studio 2022 seems to have a problem loading x86 .dlls, in my case,("Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet"), in running time using the Any CPU configuration.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.


Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

I understand that Visual Studio 2019 and earlier have x86 as the default for Any CPU and Visual Studio 2022 x64.
What I find very weird is that even configuring the whole solution to x86 still gives the same error, but this time in the Project instead of the x86 .dll file, while in Visual Studio 2017, the same solution is running fine.

Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectName' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I have tried:

Creating an x86 & custom configuration for the whole solution.
Custom Configuration

Adding different property groups to the dll for different configurations in the C# Project File.

Forcingly removing the mismatch processor warning in the Project file.


Nothing has worked so far.
What I am expecting is what Visual Studio 2017 does as default for Any CPU to be able to run the IIS application which is working fine with the same solution.

Is this a Visual studio plugin, or a project dependency? The first line implies the former, but the rest implies the later. What kind of project are you talking about? If it is a web service it may depend on what webserver you are running, i.e. Kestrel, IIS Express, etc.

It is a web service using the Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.dll as a reference:
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">

I just created a .NET Framework console app in VS'22 and added the reference just fine? I think you're leaving out necessary details to explain your problem.

Adding the reference was not the problem, compiling was also not the problem, running the x86 .dll reference was, specifically the Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.dll old versions, I am using Version: 6.2.0.0

Verify if you have Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.dll that is for 32bit or 64bit architecture. Probably now you have 64bit version and this is why it cannot be loaded.
EDIT:
As Matthew Watson writes, selecting AnyCPU means that the executable will run as 64 bit on a 64 bit architecture and 32 bit on a 32 bit architecture.
EDIT 2 (SOLUTION):
One more thing to check: verify if your project is running under IIS Express 32bit or 64bit. For web projects iisexpress.exe is your executable and all dlls have to be compatible with it. You have both IIS Express versions installed on your machine, one in %PROGRAMFILES%\IIS Express and one in %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\IIS Express. On project properties (tab "Web") you can select which IIS Express version is in use.
Visual Studio 2022 is indeed using IIS x64 as default, therefore it was not possible to load the Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet changing the IIS Express Bitness to x86 will fix the problem.

It is the same .dll file added as an external reference to the project. The message I am getting is this:  There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted... It should be 32bit, this warning only shows in Visual Studio 2022

Selecting AnyCPU means that the executable will run as 64 bit on a 64 bit architecture and 32 bit on a 32 bit architecture.

This I understand, the question is why Visual Studio 2022 shows the mismatch warning, and after building the project the errors trying to Load the assemblies while any other earlier version of Visual Studio 2019 or 2017 works just fine. No errors and no warnings

One more thing to check: verify if your project is running under IIS Express 32bit or 64bit. For web projects iisexpress.exe is your executable and all dlls have to be compatible with it. You have both IIS Express versions installed on your machine, one in %PROGRAMFILES%\IIS Express and one in %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\IIS Express. On project properties (tab "Web") you can select which IIS Express version is in use.

This was the answer to my question in the end. Visual Studio 2022 is indeed using IIS x64 as default, therefore it was not possible to load the Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet changing the IIS Express Bitness to x86 fixed the problem


What I find very weird is that even configurating the whole solution to x86 is still giving the same error

It sounds like you're confusing solution configuration with project configuration. A solution configuration (the thing you're selecting in the drop down next to start) is just a collection of the actual configurations and architectures of each individual project inside that solution:


You set up your individual projects' configuration from the Configuration Manager window, as seen above.

I have tried custom configurations already, it gives me the same project Error.
